# javascript object, method to toggle values of different properties and striving to write DRY code

Tags: javascript, html, object, methods, logic

I am trying to write a method for my object that listens for a button to be clicked and depending on which button is clicked toggle that corresponding object property between 1 and 0. I may be way off track but can i accomplish this with one method and the "this" keyword? my code below is my progress but I am stuck.http://jsfiddle.net/eh8L5cg1/

```
<input type="button" id="buttonOne" value="toggle buttonOne" />
<input type="button" id="buttonTwo" value="toggle buttonTwo" />
<input type="button" id="buttonThree"  value="toggle buttonThree" />

var controlPannel = {
    buttonOne : 0,
    buttonTwo :  0,
    buttonThree : 0
    toggleState: function() {

        $('button').click( function() {

            if (controlpannel.this == 0 ) {
                controlpannel.this = 1;
            } else {
                controlpannel.this = 0;
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can ;)
See my comments in the code. And here's a link to the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bmartinelle/eh8L5cg1/1/

```
 var controlPannel = {
    buttonOne : 0,
    buttonTwo :  0,
    buttonThree : 0,
    toggleState: function() {
        $(':button').click( function() {
            //"this" is the button - you need to fetch the id to access the property or your controlPannel
            console.log(controlPannel[this.id]);
            if (controlPannel[this.id] == 0 ) { //JS is case-sensitive - so make sure you use proper camelCasing
                console.log("toggle to 1");
                controlPannel[this.id] = 1;
            } else {
                controlPannel[this.id] = 0;
                console.log("toggle to 0");
            }
        });
     }

}
controlPannel.toggleState(); //be sure to actually assign the click handlers to your buttons!
```

Comment: Awsome! What does this part mean ':button' ? the : is new to me.

Comment: That's a way to select all "buttons" on your page